# Windows Communication Foundation Callbacks

Tags: wcf, callback

I have a WCF callback server.The server invokes callbacks on registered clients every 2 seconds. After few  hours, the communication channel on the client gets aborted and the client stops receiving callbacks. No exception is thrown on the server side. If I restart the client without restarting the server; all is well and the client starts to receive callbacks again. I am not sure what  is causing the callback channel on the client side to abort. Note that no exception is thrown on the server side. Simply restarting the client solves the problem and the client starts receiving callbacks again, I am not sure as to why the callback channel on the client side is getting aborted in the first place after a few hours. Any suggestions will be most helpful. Thanks.

Comment: maybe there is some kind of inactivity timeout - how about sending a hearbeat to the server from the client once in an hour, for now just to see if this helps

Comment: Thanks - will give that a try. I was initially sending heartbeats from server to client - but I think I should do the other way around. Will keep you posted.